# Spring + Angularjs can't change post to put

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

When I use post method it works fine, but when I try to change it to put server do not recieve object.

UserController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{user}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.updateRow(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

user_service.js:

```
updateUser: function(user, id){

                    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/user/', user)
                        .then(
                        function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        },
                        function (errResponse) {
                            console.error('Error while updating user');
                            return $q.reject(errResponse);
                        }
                    );

            },
```

How can I change it to put method?

Using PUT:

UserController.java:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{user}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.updateRow(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

user_service.js:

```
  updateUser: function(user, id){
                    return $http.put('http://localhost:8080/user/', user)
                        .then(
                        function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        },
                        function (errResponse) {
                            console.error('Error while updating user');
                            return $q.reject(errResponse);
                        }
                    );

            },
```

Comment: Instead of showing us the code which uses POST and which works fine, show us the code that uses PUT and doesn't work. Tell us, precisely, what you expect it to do and what it does instead. "It's not working" is a much too vague description.

Comment: Did you change it in both Angular and Spring?

Comment: @Luka Jacobowitz, Yes.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I added code that uses PUt.

Comment: And did you add a `User` after `http://localhost:8080/user/`? Because `/user/{user}` won't match if you don't.

Comment: @Luka Jacobowitz, Thank you. it was a problem. Please add answer, I will mark it!

Comment: you should pass a parameter to your HttpRequest ( {user} ) unless you don't use it (in this case remove the {user}. and try to cast the object that you send by using **angular.toJson(user)**, and in the server side add **consumes="application/json"** to the **@RequestMapping**

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to upvote and accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the id in the URL. Otherwise your route won't match `/user/{user}`. It should look something like this:

```
updateUser: function(user, id){
      return $http.put('http://localhost:8080/user/' + id, user)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function (errResponse) {
                console.error('Error while updating user');
                return $q.reject(errResponse);
            }
      );

},
```